# return Button or Custom component from method definition in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
state = {
        isGetOnceButtonClicked: false
    }

doAddItems(){  

    this.state.isGetOnceButtonClicked= true;
}

buttonToggle(){

    if(!this.state.isGetOnceButtonClicked){
        return(                                
            <Button 
                type = "clear"
                title="Get Once"
                onPress={() => this.doAddItems()}
            />                        
        )
    }else{
        return(                                             
            <InputNumberSpinner></InputNumberSpinner>                
        )
    }

}


render() {   



    return(

    <ScrollView>

        <View > 
             { this.buttonToggle() }
        </View>

    </ScrollView>
}
```

I'm new to react-native. I want to show the component dynamically. So created the method in which return the button if condition satisfies else return created custom component but unfortunately it is showing error like "Text strings must be rendered within a  component" If we return strings like "something" then it works fine but it throwing error whenever we are returning other than Text.

Comment: Can you provide the whole JS file? You have the wrong formatting code, syntax error

Comment: @FreakyCoder Thanks for your response but there is no syntax error

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView>

    <View > 
         { this.state.isGetOnceButtonClicked ? <InputNumberSpinner /> : <Button 
            type = "clear"
            title="Get Once"
            onPress={() => this.doAddItems()}
        />     }
    </View>

</ScrollView>
```

use a ternary operator for these kinds of tasks, if the value is true then it will show the spinner and if not, it will show the button

make sure to have a function that toggles the state of the button so buttonToggle will be like this:

```
buttonToggle(){
    this.setState({isGetOnceButtonClicked: !this.state.isGetOnceButtonClicked});
}
```

Comment: But  doAddItems() method is not called. If we place Alert in place of this.doAddItems() method that works fine. Could you please tell me how to resolve this.

onPress = { () => this.doAddItems() } on press this button control doesnt enter into the method definition but

onPress = { () => Alert.alert('here") } this works fine.

Comment: @sash no need for your doAddItem since buttonToggle (that I have written above) does the job unless your intentions for doAddItems is something else. 

the previous doAddItems doesn't update the state because updating the state only occurs when you use the setState function so if you used buttonToggle it should work fine